# Spark: java.io.IOException: No space left on device. some tasks are writing more more data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I got the `java.io.IOException: No space left on device` error.

I got the following:
[image]

in 200 tasks, there are some tasks which are running long lone time. and I checked the `shuffle write size`. the long running tasks are writing too many data.

How to make each task to write similar size data?

*UPDATE*

I dumped two data frames on HDFS. then, I wrote a spark job to read them and join  them. the codes are above.

```
    val df1 = spark.read.json(s"hdfs://xxx/user/yyy/m_${today_}").repartition($"id").cache()
    val df2 = spark.read.json(s"hdfs://xxx/user/yyy/tmp_${today_}").repartition($"id").cache()

    val combined_df = df2.join(df1, Seq("id"), "left_outer").cache()

    val cnt = combined_df.count() // get count

    combined_df
      .coalesce(PARTITIONS)
      .write
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .json(s"hdfs://xxx/user/yyy/data_$today_}_aa")
```

Still, some tasks failed because of no space error:

[image]

Comment: If the shuffle size differes from other sizes, this means that you have a data skew. Then you need to solve the data skew problem.

Comment: Absolutely correct @JiayiLiao . To solve this, try to repartition the initial dataframe based on one or multiple columns which has a good distribution.